# How to create a save_model.pb from .data and .index checkpoints files?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working with TensorFlow and I have two checkpoint files:

- a `.data` file
- a `.index` file.

Using these, I would like to generate a `saved_model.pb` file.

I have tried using the existing python files:

- `export_inference_graph.py`
- `exporter_main_v2.py`

but both did not work.

Comment: You need to load the checkpoints  manually and then save the model as a ‘saved_model.pb’ format when tensorflow scripts are not working for generating a ‘saved_model.pb’ file from the checkpoint filles.
Kindly use this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) to step by step instructions to follow the save an load the models.